# node-oracledb on M1 Mac

Tags: apple-m1, node-oracledb

I'm trying to connect to my university's Oracle DB. I wrote a simple backend that is working on my Windows machine but I can't get it working on my M1 Mac. You can find my repo [here](https://github.com/GoonerBrian/node-oracledb-on-m1-mac) and here is the core of it,

```
const express = require('express');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
    try {
      console.log("Success");
      oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: process.env.HOME + '/Downloads/instantclient_19_8'});
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Failure");
      console.error('Whoops!');
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
}
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;
dotenv.config();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{console.log(`listen to port ${PORT}`);})

database_initialized = false

async function init_database() {
    // The following should be wrapped in a try/catch
    await oracledb.createPool({
        user: process.env.USER_NAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        connectionString: process.env.CONNECTION_STRING
    });
    console.log("Successfully created connection pool");
    database_initialized = true
}

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send('Hello world!');
});

app.get('/get-customers', (req,res) => {
    async function fetchDataCustomers(){
        try {
            const connection = await oracledb.getConnection();

            oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_ARRAY;

            const query = process.env.QUERY_STR;;

            const result = await connection.execute(query);
            console.log("Completed request");
            
            try {
                await connection.close();
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log("Encountered an error closing a connection in the connection pool.");
            }
            
            return result;
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
    }

    fetchDataCustomers().then(dbRes => {
        res.send(dbRes);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send(err);
    })
})

init_database();
```

I found someone who was nice enough to provide [detailed instructions](https://gist.github.com/LeZuse/bf838718ff2689c5fc035c5a6825a11c) on using Rosetta to switch to the x64 version nvm, but my `oracledb.createPool()` function doesn't seems to be working on my M1 Mac (this works on my Windows machine). By that I mean the try block fails and drops to the catch block and prints "listen to port 5000" followed by repeatedly printing the console.log message. There are no other errors messages printed to the terminal.

On my M1 Mac, I follow the linked instructions and run `nvm use intel` and `node -e 'console.log(process.arch)'` to verify I'm using `x64`. On both machines, I can then run:

- `npm init -y`
- `npm i --save express`
- `npm i --save-dev nodemon dotenv oracledb cors`
- and `node server.js` to test the connection.

On my Windows machine, I connect and can then go on to check the endpoint I created (not included here but can be seen in the github repo I linked above). On my M1 Mac, I just get the message in the catch block telling me that an error was encountered. I want to be able to connect to an Oracle DB from my M1 Mac but it seems I don't yet have the skills to figure it out on my own. Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
After pulling `oracledb.createPool()` out of the try/catch I got the following:

```
listen to port 5000
(node:47913) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 0x0001): tried: 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (errno=62), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (errno=62), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have the 64-bit Oracle Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package libraries in
/usr/local/lib or set by calling oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: "/my/instant_client_directory"}).
Oracle Instant Client can be downloaded from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html

    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async init_database (/Users/my-name/workspaces/node-oracle-test-project/back-end/server.js:30:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:47913) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:47913) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I then re-ran `npm install oracledb` and I'm getting

```
oracledb ********************************************************************************
oracledb ** Node-oracledb 5.5.0 installed in Node.js 19.3.0 (darwin, x64)
oracledb **
oracledb ** To use node-oracledb:
oracledb ** - Oracle Client libraries (64-bit) must be available.
oracledb ** - Follow the installation instructions:
oracledb **   https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instosx
oracledb ********************************************************************************
```

So I'm following the link and trying to find how to install Oracle Client libraries.

I'm following the instructions [here](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#manual-installation) but I'm not sure how to proceed. I ran `/Volumes/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru/install_ic.sh` as it says but I'm not where to move instantclient_19_8 so that it's accessible. I tried moving `instantclient_19_8` to `/Users/brian` but that didn't resolve the error message.

I found [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/avoiding-the-dpi-1047-error-with-nodejs-node-oracledb-5-on-macos-and-windows) and added the suggested conditional to my code. Getting a new error.

```
(node:51947) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ORA-24415: Missing or null username.
    at async init_database (/Users/brian/workspaces/node-oracle-test-project/back-end/server.js:42:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:51947) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:51947) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Is there a solution? Will I just resolve one error to be greeted by another? Am I just wasting my time?

Comment: Define 'doesn't seems to be working'.  What is the error message `err`?  Where do you actually call `init_database()`?  (Update your question with the details.)

Comment: @ChristopherJones I updated the code to show the entire file since `init_database()` is called on the last line. I also further explained what I mean by 'doesn't seem to be working'. Please let me know if there are more details I should include. I've included all that I know to include.

Comment: @ChristopherJones THANK YOU! I really thought I included enough detail but I dug deeper and was able to resolve the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pulling oracledb.createPool() out of the try/catch I got the following:

```
listen to port 5000
(node:47913) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 0x0001): tried: 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (errno=62), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (errno=62), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have the 64-bit Oracle Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package libraries in
/usr/local/lib or set by calling oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: "/my/instant_client_directory"}).
Oracle Instant Client can be downloaded from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html

    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async init_database (/Users/my-name/workspaces/node-oracle-test-project/back-end/server.js:30:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:47913) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:47913) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I then re-ran npm install oracledb and I'm got

```
oracledb ********************************************************************************
oracledb ** Node-oracledb 5.5.0 installed in Node.js 19.3.0 (darwin, x64)
oracledb **
oracledb ** To use node-oracledb:
oracledb ** - Oracle Client libraries (64-bit) must be available.
oracledb ** - Follow the installation instructions:
oracledb **   https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instosx
oracledb ********************************************************************************
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#install-the-free-oracle-instant-client-basic-package) to install Instant Client but actually found [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/avoiding-the-dpi-1047-error-with-nodejs-node-oracledb-5-on-macos-and-windows) to easier to follow (because I stopped reading the doc once I thought I got what I needed). There is an issue with getting my credentials from my `.env` that I need to figure out but I'd consider that to be out of scope to my original post. This will work so long as the `process.env` values are hard coded. (I know. Fixing that is the next step.) I will update the GitHub repo I linked in the original post and hopefully others will find things easier than I did.

Update: The `.env` issue turned out to be an issue with where I was storing it. On my Windows machine I was able to put it in the parent directory (sibling to my `.gitignore`) but on my Mac I had to put it in the `back-end` directory.

Comment: I'm glad you resolved the issue.  I wrote that blog & doc.  What did you prefer in the blog?  Let me know so I can improve the doc.  (PS you might like https://github.com/oracle-samples/oracle-db-examples/tree/main/javascript/rest-api)

Comment: @ChristopherJones I'm re-reading the doc and see that the same material is there. Here I was thinking the line in the blog about people not reading the docs was harsh. Lol! I would say the blog "reads" better. It felt more like being walked through the steps with less room for (mis)interpretation. I have to admit, I had so much trouble with this prior to today that I was skimming. I had given up until someone commented on 'detailed instructions' I linked above. I'll check out the repo you linked. Thanks again!

Comment: The blog format does allow for a less formal approach.  When the doc is refreshed, I'll see if it can be nicer.  Some of your base problems will go away when we have our node-oracledb Thin mode, see https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1533

Comment: Thanks. I just subscribed to the issue.